# Blender moving f-curve Z location moves object diagonally instead of on the Z axis

Tags: animation, fcurves

[This is what I have](http://gfycat.com/periodiclegalleonberger)

As you can see in my case when I move the Z location in the F- curve it moves it diagonally for some reason. I want to move it on the Z- axis. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the object is parented to another, it will change its global axis

Comment: I made sure the object is not parented but the issue is still there

Comment: could you please share the file (at least your cube)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is rotation involved?  Fcurves will move object on local z axis.  Using GZ (global) and GZZ in 3dview willl display the axis.  Ok having looked at your gif that's exactly what it is. The local Z axis of default cube is the normal of top face.  That's where it's heading.

Comment: Is there a way to change to global Z-axis? or do I have to manually keframe it?